# Standard python classes that support math operators?

Tags: python, boolean

Which types and classes in the Python standard library support math operations but are not really numbers?

The two that I know of are:

- `list` in general, and strings in particular,
- `tuples` too
- `bool` values: this is the one surprised me

Are there other ones?

Note: to my way of thinking, `datetime`'s act like numbers to me so they're OK.

The context is that  I'm trying to write a function that allows for interpolation on arbitrary types.

My first idea is the following:

```
def weighted_combine( val1, val2, weight):
    ''' Return the weighted combination of val1 and val2
        @arg weight : 0 => ignore val2, 1 => ignore val1
                      0.5 => 50/50 mix of val1, val2
    '''
    try:
        # if I can do math, do it
        return val1+(val2-val1)*weight
    except TypeError,e:
        pass
    # otherwise pick the predominant value
    if weight>0.5:
        return val2
    else:
        return val1
```

Figuring that this should work right on just about any type.  until I checked if you can do math on bool values (and numpy arrays of bool vals), so now I need to add explicit type checking for these special cases (since I want to use the "pick closer" logic for bools), so I need to know if there are other special types I'd need to consider in this case.

Example results:

```
In [4]: True+(False-True)*0.2
Out[4]: 0.8

In [8]: a=scipy.array( [True, False, True])

In [9]: a+(a-a)*0.2
Out[9]: array([ 1.,  0.,  1.])
```

Comment: "`bool` values: this is the one surprised me"? Really? There is a long history of booleans being treated as `int`s in C and other languages. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) clearly states that `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: I had thought that when True/False were changed into "keywords" (or the precise term is), that they'd no longer be isomorphic to numbers, and it's not part of my style to rely on that feature in C++.

Comment: Well, you *can* rely on it in Python. I believe it's stated in multiple places in the documentation, and also in the [PEP 285](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) which proposed the `bool` type. In certain circumstances it turns out useful to use a boolean value as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a dirty hack:

```
>>> [i for i in dir(__builtins__) if hasattr(getattr(__builtins__, i), "__add__")]
['False', 'True', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__name__', 'bool', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'complex', 'float', 'int', 'list', 'str', 'tuple']
```

So:

- False
- True
- **bytearray**
- **bytes**
- **complex**
- float
- int
- list
- str
- tuple

from builtins, but there'll be more in standard libraries, I can think of `collections`, `decimals` and much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the subclasses of `object` and check whether they have the `__add__` method. To get the subclasses use the `__subclasses__()` method. Here's an implementation for python3.3+:

```
def find_all_classes(pred, *, start_cls=object, operation=lambda x: x):
    if pred(start_cls):
            yield operation(start_cls)
    for subclass in type.__subclasses__(start_cls):
        yield from find_all_classes(
            pred,
            start_cls=subclass,
            operation=operation,
        )
```

This however may count classes twice if more than one reference is found, which is possible due to multiple inheritance etc. A more accurate implementation would be:

```
def find_all_classes(pred, *, start_cls=object, operation=lambda x: x, found=None):
    if found is None:
        found = set()
    if start_cls in found:
        return
    found.add(start_cls)

    if pred(start_cls):
            yield operation(start_cls)
    for subclass in type.__subclasses__(start_cls):
        yield from find_all_classes(
            pred,
            start_cls=subclass,
            operation=operation,
            found=found,
        )
```

Example usage:

```
In [2]: result = list(find_all_classes(lambda cls: hasattr(cls, '__add__')))

In [3]: len(result)
Out[3]: 232

In [4]: result[:10]
Out[4]: 
[builtins.weakcallableproxy,
 builtins.weakproxy,
 builtins.int,
 builtins.bool,
 inspect._ParameterKind,
 builtins.bytearray,
 builtins.bytes,
 multiprocessing.process.AuthenticationString,
 numpy.bytes_,
 builtins.list]
```

In a fresh IPython terminal there are *232* distinct classes that support the `+` operator.

```
In [8]: len(list(find_all_classes(lambda cls: hasattr(cls, '__sub__'))))
Out[8]: 75
```

But there are only 75 that support `-`. The difference is probably due to the fact that a lot of the classes that allow `+` are actually sequences and not numeric types, so they use `+` to "concatenate" in some way, but `-` doesn't make any sense.

---

In your case I don't know whether it makes any sense to check all these values, or even some of these. You could try to convert the result to the original `dtype`, however this would require special-casing numpy's arrays etc.

If you have some specific special-case that you want to support, then it makes sense to add it, but there isn't a simple way to support *any* object with arithmetic operations and producing a reasonable result, because `+`, `-` and `*` work quite differently between types. I'd simply leave it to duck-typing and say that the function should be used with numerical inputs or inputs of type some-chosen-special-cases.